# C++ fixed length string class?

Tags: c++, string

Is there anything like this in Standard C++ / [STL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library)?  Ideally it should be constructed like

```
fstring s = fstring(10);
```

I need to sometimes construct or have a string of fixed size. Sometimes to be able to read / write only that many characters into a stream.

*Edit:*

Note that the size is only known at runtime, and is different from one to the other.  But all of the `fstring`s should know how to work together and have all the fancy `string` behavior.

Comment: I'm a bit rusty but how does that differ from a char[]?

Comment: @Lazarus - a std::string-esque fixed-string class could offer a lot more functionality, including overriding <</>>, than the basic char[] type.  It's also AFAIK not possible to have std::vector<char[10]>, but would be possible to have std::vector<fixed_string<10> >.

Comment: What "fancy" string behavior do you want to use?  It would help us provide a better answer if we knew the subset of string's member functions you were using.

Comment: fancy stuff include input and output from streams (including padding and reading only the required chars), string subscripts, iterators, and such.
Seems i'll need to write my own.

Comment: I think you can just wrap a string, if you can live with it that the string may allocate more memory than your fstring allows one to use.

Comment: I'm working on a standard std::fixed_string<N> class.  See N4121 and https://github.com/tomazos/fixed_string.

Comment: As of Boost 1.66: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__static_string.html Note that the capacity is fixed at compile time, so not quite what the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 11):

The closest approximation today is `boost::array<char, 10>`

Answer (score 5):

Use e.g.

```
std::tr1::array<char, 10>
```

Comment: Now that C++11 has been here for a while one can use std::array at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array.

Answer (score 2):

How about inheriting `std::string` privately then exposing a smaller interface with `using`, and writing your own << and >> functions?

Answer (score 2):

I've been using something like this for strings allocated on stack or as a part of another object. Which in release becomes a char*

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define STR_DEBUG
#endif

#define FIXED_STRING( maxSize ) ReservedString<maxSize> _Tmp##__LINE__; 

class FixedString{
public:
    FixedString& operator =( char const * const pStr );
    //FixedString& operator =( FixedString const &pStr );
    operator const char*() const { return mStr; }
    const char* cStr() const { return mStr; }
    FixedString& operator +=(const char *pStr);
    bool equals( const char *pStr );
    bool beginsWith( const char *pStr );
    /// rises ASSERT if not enough
    void ensureEnoughForNMore( int NMoreSymbols );
protected:
    char *mStr;
    #ifdef STR_DEBUG
        ui16 mMaxLength;
    #endif

private:
    #ifdef STR_DEBUG
        FixedString( char *str, ui16 maxLength ): mStr(str), mMaxLength(maxLength) {}
    #else
        FixedString( char *str ): mStr(str) {}
    #endif
    template<int>
    friend  class ReservedString;
};

template <int MAX_LENGTH> class ReservedString{
public:
    operator FixedString() { 
        #ifdef STR_DEBUG
            return FixedString( mBuf, MAX_LENGTH );
        #else
            return FixedString( mBuf );
        #endif
    }   
private:
    char mBuf[MAX_LENGTH+1];
};
```

Answer (score 2):

With ISO C++ +17 you can do this

```
#include <string_view>
......
char dataBuffer[BUFF_SIZE];
auto commandString = std::string_view{ dataBuffer };
......
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use std::basic_string from STL as a fixed string class?

You can use the constructor

```
basic_string(
   size_type _Count,
   value_type _Ch,
   const allocator_type& _Al = Allocator ( )
);
```

as initializer.

**Later edit:**
Example:

```
std::string my10CharStringInitializedWithSpace( 10, ' ');
```

Comment: Problem is, the created string does not do any trimming / padding, or ensuring its 10 char limit.

Comment: For that, you need to define your own class, if you want an encapsulated solution, or to use what exists on the market. See boost string algorithms for trimming: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/string_algo.html

Answer (score 1):

There's probably something in boost that provides this (the closest I've personally seen is Boost.Array, which is insufficient).  However, if you're just looking to model the "important subset" of `std::string`, it's not very difficult to make a fixed-length equivalent:

```
template <size_t N>
class fixed_string
{
    // ... interface looks like std::string
};
```

For anyone asking about why bothering to do this at all, the main benefit is to avoid memory allocation without losing most of the useful `std::string` API.  If there's another way to do this with `std::allocator`, I'd be curious to know.

Comment: I tried, but I don't see how this can work. The problem is, the string may (will) request more memory from the allocator than it needs currently. E.g, when I set the limit of my allocator on 32 characters, I only managed to push back 16 characters out of 25.

Answer (score 1):

With C++11, one can go for

```
std::array<char,10> s;
```

Also std::string equivalent can always be constructed, when required

```
std::string s2(std::begin(s), std::end(s));
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed something like this as well.  I built a solution based on istream_iterator with an added constraint on block_size.

You can find my repository [block_iterator on GitHub](https://github.com/jac18281828/istream_block_iterator)

It is only a single header [here](https://github.com/jac18281828/istream_block_iterator/blob/main/include/istream_block.h)

This works like istream_iterator so you split a string into 3 character strings as follows:

```
constexpr auto N = 3;
const auto example = "AAABBBCCC";
std::istringstream ss(example);
std::vector<std::string> blocks{};
std::copy(istream_block_iterator<std::string>(ss, N), istream_block_iterator<std::string>(),std::back_inserter(blocks));
```

Answer (score 0):

C style character array?

```
char label[10] = "a string";
```

Comment: That misses all of the member functions of an STL container - even the subset that could apply to a fixed-length container.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you don't want to use `std::string` because you're worried it might silently expand on you.  I see a couple of options:

1. Use a raw C-style string and the functions from `cstdio` that take a length argument (e.g., `fgets`).
2. Use a `std::vector<char>`.

Comment: But `std::vector<char>` will silently expand, too! Take http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571901/1571978#1571978

Comment: Only if you ask it to.  `operator>>` on a string will automagically expand the string to accomodate whatever you're reading.  With a vector you'd have to explicitly insert or push_back past your imposed limit.

Comment: Ah, you're referring to `operator>>`. This wasn't clear from your posting.

Comment: @sbi next question: how would you actually `operator>>` into that `vector<char>`... :|