# Declaring a string of fixed size

Tags: c++

In C we do

```
char buffer[100];
```

Is there a way to declare a fixed size `std::string`?

Comment: What problem do you want to solve with a fixed-size string?

Comment: You have the option of doing *exactly* the same thing in C.  Youncould also so an array<char>.  Or you could just not put more than 100 chars in a string.  It depends kn what you're trying to do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1571901/c-fixed-length-string-class

Comment: You can use std::vector<char>

Comment: There is a third-party function, similar to `void do_something(char * buffer, int buffer_sz);` I am determined to use `std::string` and convert it to cstring when needed. The problem is `buffer_sz` has to be known at compile time. So I was wondering if there is a way to declare a fixed size `std::string` ...

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just use `std::string`, but ignore the functions that allow you to insert or remove characters from it?

Answer (score 14):

You can use the [string::reserve](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/reserve/) method like this

```
  std::string s;
  s.reserve(100);
```

But this isn't fixed size, because you can add more chars to the string with string::push_back for example.

Answer (score 8):

In c++17, there will be `std::string_view` which offers the same (immutable) interface as `std::string`.

In the meantime, you can wrap a char array and add whatever services to it you choose, eg:

```
template<std::size_t N>
struct immutable_string
{
    using ref = const char (&)[N+1];
    constexpr immutable_string(ref s)
    : s(s)
    {}

    constexpr auto begin() const { return (const char*)s; }
    constexpr auto end() const { return begin() + size(); }
    constexpr std::size_t size() const { return N; }
    constexpr ref c_str() const { return s; }
    ref s;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, immutable_string s)
    {
        return os.write(s.c_str(), s.size());
    }
};

template<std::size_t NL, std::size_t NR>
std::string operator+(immutable_string<NL> l, immutable_string<NR> r)
{
    std::string result;
    result.reserve(l.size() + r.size());
    result.assign(l.begin(), l.end());
    result.insert(result.end(), r.begin(), r.end());
    return result;
}

template<std::size_t N>
auto make_immutable_string(const char (&s) [N])
{
    return immutable_string<N-1>(s);
}

int main()
{
    auto x = make_immutable_string("hello, world");
    std::cout << x << std::endl;

    auto a = make_immutable_string("foo");
    auto b = make_immutable_string("bar");
    auto c = a + b;
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't know what you want to do, but with an `std::array<char, 100> buffer;` you should do fine.

You can then get a string like this:

```
std::string str(std::begin(buffer),std::end(buffer);
```

Answer (score 5):

As of [Boost 1.66](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__static_string.html): A non-allocating string that emulates the interface of `std::basic_string`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `std::array`, which is the C++ method of doing exactly what you did in C.

```
std::array<char, 100> buffer;
```

If you're worried about stack overflow due to large buffer sizes (like, for example, if that `100` is a stand-in for `1'000'000`) you could dynamically allocate it instead.

```
std::unique_ptr<std::array<char, 100>> buffer = std::make_unique<std::array<char, 100>>();
```

Since your interface takes a `char *` as its operand, and this object allows you to query for its size at runtime, this ought to suffice.

Answer (score 1):

check this https://github.com/m3janitha/fixed_size_string. you can replace `char buffer[n];` with `fss::fixed_size_string<n> buffer;`